# Use combinations to explain why $C(n, k) = C(n, n-k)$ for any $n, k ∈ ℕ, 0 ≤ k ≤ n$.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, combinations, factorial, word-problem

- **Previous subquestion:**

Use the formula $\begin{pmatrix}n\\r\end{pmatrix}$ = $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ to show that $\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}n\\n-k\end{pmatrix}$ for any *n*, *k* ∈ ℕ, 0 ≤ *k* ≤ *n*.

- **My answer:**

$\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix}$ = $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

$\begin{pmatrix}n\\n-k\end{pmatrix}$ = $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(n-(n-k))!}$

$\begin{pmatrix}n\\n-k\end{pmatrix}$ = $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(n-n+k)!}$

$\begin{pmatrix}n\\n-k\end{pmatrix}$ = $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$

∴ $\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}n\\n-k\end{pmatrix}$

- **The question I'm having trouble with:**

Use combinations to explain why this is true.

Comment: Do you want a combinatorial interpretation of this equality ?

Comment: Yes please, @N.H.

Comment: (not fast enough sorry ! )

Comment: You can still answer it if you like, it always helps to see a concept explained in different ways :-) @N.H.

Comment: My answer would be the same as the other answers : the main idea is that choosing $k$ objects is also choosing $n-k$ objects (the objects which are left).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every choice of $k$ objects necessarily determines the complementary choice of $n-k$ objects.

If there are ten bottles on a wall, when you take three down, seven are left. The number of ways of taking three is the same as the number of ways of leaving seven. When you take seven down, there are three left. Whether you consider this as $\binom{10}{3}$ or $\binom{10}{7}$ you get the same answer.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation, @Shai. Do you think that this answer sums it up well enough? - $\binom{n}{k}$ = the number of possible combinations where _k_ is chosen and _n_-_k_ is left. $\binom{n}{n-k}$ = the number of possible combinations where _n_-_k_ is chosen and _n_-(_n_-_k_) = _n_-_n+k_ = _k_ is left. The number of possible combinations is the same whether choosing _k_ and leaving _n_-_k_ or choosing _n_-_k_ and leaving _k_.

Comment: That makes sense to me, nicely put

Answer (score 3):

$\binom nk$ is by definition the number of ways of choosing $k$ elements out of $n$. There are two ways of doing so :

- Chose $k$ elements, keep them and put the others away.
- Chose $n-k$ elements, put them away and keep the remaining $k$ ones.

Therefore there are as many ways of choosing $k$ elements among $n$, and choosing $n-k$ elements among $n$.